# Install CiviCRM alone or as Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, installation

I need your advice. What is the best ? Install CiviCRM alone or as Wordpress plugin ?

I have a wordpres website for a NPO, and I want to manage members with CiviCRM.

We are not big, and will manage approximately 100 members.

I would like to take registration for new members and cotisation (Paypal or Stripe).

There will also be fee-paying events, so I would like to make forms so that members can register for events and pay for them.

I'm afraid about integrate CiviCRM with Wordpress.I don't know if from a management point of view it wouldn't be better to have it separately.

What is your opinion on that?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Install CiviCRM with WordPress is ok, I'm use on 2 website and satisfy with this now.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot install CiviCRM standalone, you need to install it as part of a Drupal / WordPress / Joomla! / Backdrop CMS system.

Answer (score 5):

As has already been said, CiviCRM has to be installed on top of a CMS such as Drupal, WordPress or Joomla.  I have it on WordPress and it's working fine.  Some documentation about how to install on WordPress can be found here at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/
It can work using the same database as WordPress but, my advice would be to have 2 separate databases.

As you will see from the documentation, It wont install like a conventional WordPress plugin.  There is considerable more work to do.
If you are concerned about installing it as part of your main Wordpress site, you could perhaps open a subdomain such as members.mydomain.org with its own wordpress installation, and then install CiviCRM on the subdomain with appropriate links.  However this would require much more Admin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM can not be installed *alone*. You CAN install it on a server within the CMS Drupal, Joomla!, Wordpress or Backdrop but actually not make it available to the internet. You then have in actual fact probably what you would call CiviCRM *alone*.

If you do not need a website I would certainly recommend you to do that as it is much more secure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have already chimed in - but I wanted to share that you should not be concerned with integrating CiviCRM with your Wordpress installation. The only concern you may have is if you don't want the Administrators of your Wordpress site to have access to CiviCRM.  However - you can setup permission in Wordpress and create different roles using the Members plugin and you can manage permissions there and within CiviCRM.

Comment: I use the ACL feature to limit the access from say WP users and the CiviCRM users. It's seamless and refined both within WP and CiviCRM. Then, I use Groups for further refinement e.g.; only our Board can vote on certain matters so we use "Board Members" in conjunction with the Elections plugin.